# C++ Memory Leak not properly showing

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, memory-leak-detector

I'm using **_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();** from the stdlib.h and crtdbg.h to detect memory leaks, but I noticed something strange in my code.

If I do:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    MyClass* myClass = new MyClass();
    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks(); //I get a memory leak warning
}
```

However, if I do:

```
class MyClass
{
    public:
        char* NewChar();
};
char* MyClass::NewChar()
{
    char* test = new char[100];
    return test;
}

MyClass myClass; //Globally declared
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{        
    char* charPointer = myClass.NewChar();
    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks(); //No warnings
}
```

Shouldn't I get the warning since my program exited (right after **_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks()**) and there was still a new char that wasn't deleted?

How can I detect these memory leaks?

Also, using the same example above, if I add the code:

```
char* anotherPointer = charPointer; //previously filled
delete[] anotherPointer;
```

Will this delete the new char from inside the class preventing memory leaks, or should I call delete on **charPointer** as well?

Comment: Since you delete *things*, not pointers, it doesn't matter which pointer is pointing at something when you delete it. In other words, deleting through `anotherPointer` is the same thing as deleting through `charPointer`, and you should only do one of them.

Comment: OK. did the entire question just change or was it me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to catch (or have a decent shot at catching) global object leaks, try setting the CRT debug flag **_CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF** at the start of main. The flag forces a dump of detected leaks **after** global destructors.

To answer your questions:

> Shouldn't I get the warning since my program exited (right after _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks()) and there was still a new char that wasn't deleted?

Define "warning". The call to `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks()` should dump whatever is outstanding at the time. Your program exiting afterward will not do another dump unless configured to do so.

> How can I detect these memory leaks?

They should be detected properly provided you are using the debug CRT and have the `_Crt` configuration setup properly, which it mostly *is* by default.

---

The following code sets up the `_Crt` dump system to dump all objects on-demand and right before final exit (after `main()` is finished and global statics are destroyed).

```
class MyLeak
{
public:
    MyLeak() { new unsigned char[1024]; }

    char * NewChar() { return new char[1024]; }
};

MyLeak myLeak;
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int tmpFlag = _CrtSetDbgFlag( _CRTDBG_REPORT_FLAG );
    tmpFlag |= _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF;
    _CrtSetDbgFlag(tmpFlag);

    _CrtMemState ms = {0};
    _CrtMemCheckpoint(&ms);

    char *ptr = myLeak.NewChar();
    _CrtMemDumpAllObjectsSince(&ms);

    OutputDebugString("Exiting main()\n");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Debug Output Log**

```
Dumping objects ->
{69} normal block at 0x000000000048B800, 1024 bytes long.
 Data: <                > CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD 
Object dump complete.
Exiting main()
Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
{69} normal block at 0x000000000048B800, 1024 bytes long.
 Data: <                > CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD 
{68} normal block at 0x000000000048B390, 1024 bytes long.
 Data: <                > CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD 
Object dump complete.
```

Note that the first dump records just the inner allocation, since I used a checkpoint then a dump-since call. The second dump (invoked after `main()` is finished) still records them both, as they're both outstanding.

That you're leak dump after your dynamic allocation (which granted was from an object in global memory space, but that has nothing to do with the allocation, its just code allocating memory and returning it to you) does not look correct. You should be getting an object dump of *all* outstanding CRT allocations with any `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks()` invoke since the start of the program.

Answer (score 0):

Think about it. The global variable `myClass` has static storage duration. It will be destroyed after the closing brace of `main` when the program is terminating. `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks`() can't affirmatively detect is as a leak as the destructor of `MyClass` hasn't yet (rightly) been called.

Answer (score 0):

> Shouldn't I get the warning since my program exited (right after_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks())

Yes, you should get a warning, but not because of exiting, ...

> and there was still a new char that wasn't deleted?

...but because of this, i.e. because there was still a dynamically allocated *char array* that wasn't deleted.

> How can I detect these memory leaks?

Are you sure you compiled the program with _DEBUG #defined? If you did, afaik it should be detected. (Can't check myself right now and haven't used this in ages, so I can't really vouch for this.)

> Also, using the same example above, if I add the code:
>
> `char* anotherPointer = charPointer; //previously filled`
>   delete[] anotherPointer;`
>
> Will this delete the new char from inside the class preventing memory leaks, or should I call delete on charPointer as well?

This will delete the dynamically allocated character array. After this `charPointer` is a *dangling pointer*, which must not be used any more - neither dereferenced, nor delete[]'d.  (The same applies for `anotherPointer`.)  Deleting the deleted array again, whether through the same pointer or another variable is not allowed and causes [Undefined Behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Answer (score 0):

Are you linking with the debug libraries? If you are not, you won't get the messages about non-freed memory blocks. Hint: use /MDd option.

Note that contrary to what the function name suggests, all it does is to print a list of memory blocks that you've not yet freed. By calling it at the end of main(), you're making it report on blocks that you explicitly allocated, but did not explicitly free. So if you have singleton objects allocated dynamically, they will be reported as a leak whereas you might quite legitimately be freeing them using a function connected through the _atexit() mechanism.